# What is the proper type for moxy/getValueByXPath() for XML node?

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I have the following `xpath` expression and call to `getValueByXpath`:

```
String xpath = "/msg:L1MessageRequest/msg:Header";
Object val = jaxbContexL1.getValueByXPath(message.getPayload(), xpath, resolver, Object.class);
```

I am getting `null` value back from call to `getValueByXPath()` method when I try to pass in an expression that should be returning an XML set of elements. For example, I should get back:

```
<msg:Header>
<hdr:MsgID>LA00000000000110wAA11111</hdr:MsgID>
<hdr:MsgType>request</hdr:MsgType>
<hdr:MsgTimestamp>2016-01-05T09:00:00-04:00</hdr:MsgTimestamp>
.. more stuff ...
</msg:Header>
```

Since I do not know what the expected return type is, I just passed in `Object.class`, but not sure if that is the problem. Does anyone know what java type's class I should be using to return an XML fragment from the method?  I know the expression and input XML document is correct, as I tried it with an `xpath` parser directly.